# Show data except last row

Tags: r, plotly, linechart

I have a dataset of monthly data for a whole year and in it I also have last row that carries monthly average that I would like to use as a label in the chart.

I would like to keep it in a dataset but not show its value in the graph (except for the label). Is there a way to omit this last row in the plotly formula (something like "for axis y value use variable *a* but only on positions 1-12")?

My code:

```
library(plotly)
library(readxl)

data1 <- read_excel("data all.xlsx", sheet = "Main_hard")

fig <- plot_ly(data1, x = ~yearmonth, y = ~a, name = 'name 1', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers',
           line = list(color = 'rgb(0,54,87)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(0,54,87)', size = 8))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~b, name = 'name 2', line = list(color = 'rgb(186,251,0)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(186,251,0)', size = 8))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~c, name = 'name 3', line = list(color = 'rgb(108,0,159)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(108,0,159)', size = 8))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~d, name = 'name 4', line = list(color = 'rgb(54,156,0)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(54,156,0)', size = 8))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~e, name = 'name 5', line = list(color = 'rgb(0,78,216)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(0,78,216)', size = 8))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~f, name = 'name 6', line = list(color = 'rgb(227,129,0)', width = 4), marker = list(color = 'rgb(227,129,0)', size = 8))

label_1 <- list(
  xref = 'paper',
  yref = 'y',
  x = 1.05,
  y = data1$a[12],
  xanchor = 'right',
  yanchor = 'middle',
  text = ~paste(a[13], '%'),
  font = list(family = 'sans',
              size = 12,
              color = 'rgb(0,54,87)'),
  showarrow = FALSE)

fig <- fig %>% layout(title = 'title',
                      xaxis = list(title = 'month'),
                      yaxis = list(title = 'count'),
                      annotations = label_1)

fig
```

Comment: Try ```fig <- plot_ly (data1[,c(1:12)] , ....``` .

Comment: @ShubhamPujan Thanks for advise. It works slightly different way: `fig <- plot_ly(data1, x = ~yearmonth[c(1:12)], y = ~a[c(1:12)],...`

Comment: Shubham has a typo - comma in the wrong place. You should be able to do drop the row from the data as passed to the plot like `fig <- plot_ly(data1[1:12, ], ...)` or more generally `plot_ly(head(data1, -1), ...)` and not have to retype `1:12` for every variable.